# href match with links

Tags: jquery, regex

I've got this piece of code, but i wanna fix it because the if statement if it's true it's empty... any ideas of how i can make it false always?

using ! inside the if it's not working

```
var $link = $(this).attr("href");
if ($link.match(/^(?:.*?\.)?(domain)\.net(?:\/.*)?$/))  {
}else {
    $(this).attr("href",'http://links.domain.net/?url='+$link);
}
```

This it's in jquery in this function

```
/* change_links */
(function($) {
    $.fn.change_links = function() {
        $('.post a:not([href^=mailto])').each(function() {
            var $link = $(this).attr("href");
            if ($link.match(/^(?:.*?\.)?(taringacs)\.net(?:\/.*)?$/))  {
            }else {
                $(this).attr("href",'http://links.taringacs.net/?url='+$link);
            }
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [RegExp.test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

```
/* change_links */
(function($) {
    $.fn.change_links = function() {

        $('.post a:not([href^=mailto])').each(function() {
            var $link = $(this).attr("href");

            if (! /^(?:.*?\.)?(taringacs)\.net(?:\/.*)?$/.test($link))  {
                $(this).attr("href",'http://links.taringacs.net/?url='+$link);
            }

        });

    }

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I don't wanna use an empty true statement, using that it's the same i've got!

Comment: Modified the code. I thought you were going to add something to the if condition.

Comment: Ah nice. You might want to accept the correct answer in that case :)

Answer (score 0):

The [`match()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) method returns an array of matches, you'll have to check its length.

```
if ($link.match(/^(?:.*?\.)?(domain)\.net(?:\/.*)?$/).length == 0)  {
    $(this).attr("href",'http://links.domain.net/?url='+$link);
}
```